# tomcat startup.sh trouble finding JAVA_HOME

Tags: tomcat

I am a bit puzzled by this strange behavior on CentOs 5.4 when starting Tomcat 6.0 as a service

I've added a script at /etc/init.d/tomcat that can start/stop/restart Apache Tomcat 6.0 with user 'tomcat', and registered it as service. The problem with the service is that I am getting a 'Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined'. But when type  'sudo -u tomcat echo $JAVA_HOME' I get '/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22' which is correct since I am using that JDK. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried forcing the JAVA_HOME env variable into the start script itself? Whenever I face a problem like this I find it a good troubleshooting technique to try and track down where it is losing this info by setting it in the scripts themselves.

Comment: Yes. When I insert export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22 directly in the $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh then it works no problem.

Comment: remember to insert this to the beginning of the script, rather than to the end of it.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and solved it by placing the `JAVA_HOME` variable definition on file `/etc/environment`.

Initially I had created the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable invoking:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=<path_to_my_java_home>
```

Then I realized Tomcat `startup.sh` script could not access the value of the `JAVA_HOME` variable when it was invoked with `sudo`, which is necessary to start Tomcat server.

First I tried exporting the `JAVA_HOME` variable with `sudo`, but it did not work:

```
$ sudo export JAVA_HOME=<path_to_my_java_home>
sudo: export: command not found
```

Then I tried adding the `JAVA_HOME` variable definition to `/etc/environment` file.
Here is how my `/etc/enviroment` file looks like now:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Then after invoking Tomcat `startup.sh` script with `sudo` and accessing `http://localhost:8080` the brownser brings Tomcat startup page, which states the server is setup successfully.

Comment: I have NO idea where in the starting of daemons this file gets called, but it does. This keeps me from having to put the JAVA_HOME value in each and every service's (on linux) /etc/default/$application file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the paths in /etc/profile.d/java.sh ?

Also try checking which java version it return with: which java

this should return the exact paths in java.sh if not you have a misconfiguration. in the later case uninstall all java and reinstall latest jdk.

Anyhow this posts comes in handy in your favorites for later reference.

http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=5717&forum=28

Comment: I don't have a /etc/profile.d/java.sh. Don't think that the JDK installed from rpm creates one

On all users 'java -version' returns:
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Also 'echo $JAVA_HOME' return
/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22

Answer (score 0):

In bin/catalina.sh just add JAVA_HOME for crontab as

```
# For CRONTAB
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
# END
```